# Service Broker, endpoint - do i really need a certificate to send message between two servers?

Tags: sql-server, certificate, service-broker, endpoints

Do I really need to create a certificate to send a queued message between sql servers? 
Can I use dbo authentication for the endpoint on both servers?

```
create endpoint target
state = started
as TCP
(
LISTENER_PORT = 4022
)
FOR SERVICE_BROKER (AUTHENTICATION = CERTIFICATE ????, ENCRYPTION = ENABLED);
```

**IF** I have to use a certificate, can I use a User database certificate instead of one on master? How would I go about doing this?

*I am not concerned with security at the moment. Both servers are on a closed lan, with no internet access.*

---

Sorry.I do not have profiler. I am using sql express 2005.

```
  CREATE ROUTE RoutetoTarget
    WITH
    BROKER_INSTANCE = 'xxxxxx-xxx-xx-x-x-x-x',
   SERVICE_NAME = 'LOCALReceivingService',
```

<---**that works only in instances on same server.** However once I add the target server IP with port number (the endpoint I created on target server) messages get sent into the void. They never make it to the other server.

```
ADDRESS = 'TCP://targetipadress:PORT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to at least have AUTHORIZATION DBO for both local and remote service, make sure all encryption in endpoint, and sent message is off/disabled, and lastly, DO NOT have a master key. Many online sites say Broker will not work without an encrypted master key, but doesn't seem to be true in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to use a certificate:

```
CREATE ENDPOINT ssb_target
STATE = STARTED
AS TCP 
(
    LISTENER_PORT = 4022
)
FOR SERVICE_BROKER
(
    AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS,
    ENCRYPTION = DISABLED
)
GO
```

More info: [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191264.aspx)

Comment: alter route myroute with address = tcp://ipaddress:port, service targetservice

Comment: <-this route is on my main database pointing to remote target servers service

Comment: Best way to troubleshoot is to fire up Profiler and capture the broker events (on both sender and target servers).

Comment: Nathan dont have profiler. using sql server express 2005. Any other way to check? works via instances on same server, but not via tcp with 2 servers.

Comment: Are the servers in the same domain? If so, are the SQL services running under AD domain users? And have you granted connect/send privileges for each user on the endpoints? Perhhaps you have another computer nearby with full SQL tools installed. You can always use profiler from there.

Comment: It will be on a separate server with different domain. But at the moment I am just trying to send a message between two databases on same server via TCP. It works fine via GUID so I know its setup correctly. So I do not need a certificate, but I may need permission?  Should I authorize with dbo on both ends (route and endpoint?)